# AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'find_element'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've been trying to get Python to login to a website and download a csv file (one after the other because they can take a long time, and they can't be downloaded in parallel). I can't click SENECA01 button because of ElementClickInterceptedException, so after reading stackoverflow I tried using an explicit wait.

Here's the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'find_element'
```

Here's the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from getpass import getpass
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

opt = Options()
opt.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
opt.add_argument("start-maximized")
opt.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
# Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block
opt.add_experimental_option("prefs", { \
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic": 1, 
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera": 1,
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 1, 
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1 
  })

PATH = ("C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, chrome_options=opt)
wait = WebDriverWait(webdriver, 5)

driver.get("https://xxxx.xxx-xxx.org/logon/login")
print(driver.title)

username = input("Enter in your username: ")
password = getpass("Enter your password: ")

username_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
username_textbox.send_keys(username)

password_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
password_textbox.send_keys(password)

login_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("formstylebut")
login_button.submit()

link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Big Data (CAD)")
link.click()

link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Run a Report")
link.click()

link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "SENECA01")))
link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("SENECA01")
link.click()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start using Selenium first and foremost you need:

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

---

Additionally, as per the documentation the [WebDriverWait](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#selenium.webdriver.support.wait.WebDriverWait) is defined as follows:

```
class selenium.webdriver.support.wait.WebDriverWait(driver, timeout, poll_frequency=0.5, ignored_exceptions=None)
```

Where the Constructor, takes a WebDriver instance and timeout in seconds.

As your webdriver instance is:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, chrome_options=opt)
```

So instead of *`webdriver`* you need to pass the same ***`driver`*** instance to the *WebDriverWait()* as follows:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
```

Comment: This made me realise I wasn't passing `driver` through the fixture's function. e.g.
`@pytest.fixture
def do_something() {
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 16, ignored_exceptions=StaleElementReferenceException)\
            .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button")))
        button.click()
}`
Should have been:
`@pytest.fixture
def do_something(driver) {
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 16, ignored_exceptions=StaleElementReferenceException)\
            .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button")))
        button.click()
}`

So thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
wait = WebDriverWait(webdriver, 5)
```

should be

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
```

and this is how you should use this

```
link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "SENECA01")))
```

trust it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response. So I tried that and got this instead - **ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <a href="report_exec_hc_1.php?report_id=...">SENECA01</a> is not clickable at point (100, 740). Other element would receive the click: <td align="center" class="footer" bgcolor="Black">...</td>**

Comment: I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but I did upvote and tick and feedback has been recorded. I've actually already created a ticket for the second error, but it was closed because it's been "answered before". Never mind the fact that I'm really new to Python and this error/exception is really hard to get past. Thanks for your help nonetheless.

Comment: So I should just create a new ticket and tag selenium. I'll see if I can make the ticket different enough so that it will remain on StackOverflow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239431/discussion-between-optik-and-cruisepandey).